# Calling the Sharepoint Rest services

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, odata, sharepoint-2013

Iam new to the Sharepoint Rest services and trying to access the internal Sharepoint site. The URL gives the table of data with table of info  https://company.org/sites/js/prj/Lists/St%20Codes/AllItems.aspx like

St#   Prj#  St Name

1     1001  strn1

2     1002  strn2

I am trying to access this api using the SOAP UI and the above URL in the SOAPUI returns the complete Page Source.I am trying to get the St# as a JSON  response following the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

[image]
So tried giving

https://company.org/sites/js/prj/Lists/GetByTitle('St#')/items
https://company.org/sites/js/prj/Lists/St%20Codes/GetByTitle('St#')/items

Both didnt work. How can I get the ST# as response

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with? SharePoint 2010 has a different REST endpoint URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `https://company.org/sites/js/prj/Lists/GetByTitle('St%20Codes)/items` to get all items in that list.

You would then have to traverse the return values to get each St#. If you know the St# then you just add the item id after items like so: `https://company.org/sites/js/prj/Lists/GetByTitle('St%20Codes)/items(insert_ID_here)`

Comment: You still need the /_api/web/ in the URL if you want to work with the api.